# iOS and twitter integration - getting multiple users' statuses

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

I'm interested in adding a twitter feed to my iOS app but I had a quick question: I'd like to stream the most recent updates from a group of about 10 different users - is there a way to do this directly using the twitter api? (Just to clarify - I'm trying to make an app for a sports team and id like a section where users can check out the most recent tweets from all the athletes)

I've been looking around but I can't find a way to do this directly. I'd rather not search for each account individually and have to aggregate the results. Any thoughts on how to handle this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking here: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3941 seems to make me think it cannot be done directly. They recommend creating a list and simply pulling that feed. Another idea would be creating an account that only follows the users you're interested in and pulling that feed. Not sure how appropriate that would be.

Comment: Ya thanks for the link that was really helpful. After doing some research I think the list is the way to go. Thanks!